# Perl's Mojo::XMLRPC and manipulating Mojo::Date format

Tags: datetime, perl, xml-rpc, iso8601, mojolicious

I was inspired to use [`Mojo::XMLRPC`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::XMLRPC) after reading [The Mojolicious Blog - Day 11](https://mojolicious.io/blog/2017/12/11/day-11-useragent-content-generators/). I'm having problems with [`Mojo::Date`](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojo/Date) format.

1. During `encode_xmlrpc`, `<dateTime.iso8601>` is `2023-06-14T19:45:48Z`. Instead, I need it as: `20230614T22:45:48+0300`
2. During `decode_xmlrpc`, I get an error when `<dateTime.iso8601>` is `20230608T12:00:00+0000`:

```
Garbage at end of string in strptime: +0000 at /usr/local/opt/perl/lib/perl5/5.36/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Time/Piece.pm line 598.
Perhaps a format flag did not match the actual input? at /usr/local/opt/perl/lib/perl5/5.36/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Time/Piece.pm line 598.
```

EDIT: I believe a missing `'%H:%M:%S%z'` at the front of `$time_format` array in [`XMLRPC.pm`](https://github.com/jberger/Mojo-XMLRPC/blob/6e81ee6f4abbc3fc1435148487009ddddf7defbc/lib/Mojo/XMLRPC.pm#L184) is my issue (?)

How can I instruct [`Mojo::XMLRPC`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::XMLRPC) (or [`Mojo::Date`](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojo/Date)?) to use the desired [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) format?

Sample code below:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Mojo::XMLRPC qw[encode_xmlrpc decode_xmlrpc];
use Data::Dumper;

my $e = encode_xmlrpc(call => TaregtMethod => {originTimeStamp=>Mojo::Date->new(time)});
say STDERR Dumper($e);

my $xml = <<'XML';
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<methodResponse>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value>
        <struct>
          <member>
            <name>activationDate</name>
            <value>
              <dateTime.iso8601>20230608T12:00:00+0000</dateTime.iso8601>
            </value>
          </member>
        </struct>
      </value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodResponse>
XML

my $d = decode_xmlrpc($xml);
say STDERR Dumper($d);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is at the other end.

> During `encode_xmlrpc`, `<dateTime.iso8601>` is `2023-06-14T19:45:48Z`. Instead, I need it as: `20230614T22:45:48+0300`

It's not configurable, and that's not a valid iso8601 serialization.

> During `decode_xmlrpc`, I get an error when `<dateTime.iso8601>` is `20230608T12:00:00+0000`:

That's to be expected since the string isn't a valid iso8601 serialization.

---

Valid iso8601 formats can be found in the documentation for [DateTime::Format::ISO8601](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::ISO8601).

Mojo::XMLRPC doesn't accept all of them, and it accepts many other formats that aren't part of iso8601.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and to Joel for providing the library. I'll attempt to modify it myself to solve my problem. I was hoping for a magical environment variable with a strptime string 